# Enforcing the TDD's Red/Green/Refactor culture with server-side hooks

Tags: git, unit-testing, testing, tdd

#### Background (optional)

I'm currently working on a project that our company got from previous contractors, and it's in very poor state in regard to test coverage - there are virtually no tests, and code base is very entangled and fragile, so any small changes are likely to break everything in most complex and surprising way.

To address numerous issues, we're going to start off a new project, and I'd like to prevent the team from inheriting bad culture from the old project, given that temptation to do something "quick & dirty" would be great enough.

#### Idea

So, I've though about some way to enforce TDD automatically, in the more or less the way people enforce correct code style via server-side git hooks.

In my case, the idea is to create a server-side push hook that would act on the *OLD* commit (e.g. branch HEAD before the push), and the *NEW* commit (branch HEAD after the push) in roughly the following way:

- First, separate changes in code from changes in tests. This should be easy enough if tests live in separate folder.
- Determine the list of tests that are new or have been changed.
- Run new and changed tests from the *NEW* commit on the *OLD* code. Assert that all these tests should be red. If any tests are green, this means that these tests are invalid or redundant, because tested functionality does not exist yet.
- Run new and changed tests from the *NEW* commit on the *NEW* code, capturing code coverage. Assert that all tests are green. Assert that at least all new and changed lines in the *NEW* code were covered by tests.
- Run all tests on the *NEW* code to check for regressions, capturing code coverage. Assert that all tests are green, and code coverage is complete. The point of running just a small subset of tests earlier is to smoke test. Full suite may take full few minutes to run, and few changed tests would run in almost an instant.

It also makes sense to me to provide these testing things as local hooks as well, to just test the difference between local head and remote head without having to try to push possibly broken code.

Does this make any sense, or am I missing something? Also, am I reinventing the wheel, or are there any best practices for enforcing such a thing, if "we're all consenting adults here" is not really a case?

Comment: What you want can not be achieved by git hook, you need to redefine your workflow and a continuous integration (CI) solution, IMHO.

Comment: Speak to people, teach them, have conversation about writing good software. Continuously have code review - which will be your "automatic tool" to keep codebase clean. Do not force to write TDD (test first), but you can force to have tests. Tests can be written before production code(TDD) or after - it's doesn't meter from final product point of view.

Comment: @Fabio, I don't want to enforce somebody to write tests before. This is neither possible nor practical. I want to be sure that all code committed has tests that cover it completely, so the technical debt isn't growing and is resolved immediately. You are free to first write your code, then write tests for it, whatever is more convenient for you, as long as these tests are valid and do their job. Or am I wrong in this?

Answer (score 2):

> Does this make any sense, or am I missing something?

This strikes me as a dreadful idea, as described.

I foresee two problems:

First, your *measurement* is making strong assumptions about the introduction of tests following a strict pattern, and it isn't at all obvious that the assumptions of the test hold generally.

Second, the process isn't assisting the developer, but rather is blocking the developer unless the assumptions you put into the hooks fit even in currently unforeseeable circumstances.

You might review Greg Young's talk [Stop Over Engineering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GRr4xeMn1uU); the goal of our tooling isn't to force the team to do things The One True Way in all circumstances.  The goal should be to make things easier in the circumstances that are simple to understand, and to stay out of the way in the exceptional cases.

Now, if you change things up a bit, you may have something interesting going.  If you were to apply that same measurement to all of the commits, tracking the results *without blocking the flow*, you'd have a lot of really interesting signal to review on a regular basis.  At that point, you'd have a sense for how often violations of the policy were happening, how often those violations were appropriate, and perhaps even an estimate of the cost to the team.

In other words, you could take time to refine the policies and measure their effectiveness before making them mandatory in all cases.

[git commit --no-verify](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#git-commit---no-verify) might be a sufficient escape hatch for the cases that your policy doesn't cover.

Comment: Okay, so main concern is disrupting flow, I see. But if I instead put these metrics into CI, and make CI evaluate each branch that is going to be merged, and report negative code review result (which can be overridden, of course) when appropriate, would it be good/helpful enough?

Comment: Code coverage is an indirect indicator of tests quality. If it is low then most probably tests are poor. If it is 100% it does not mean that code base is good, is not fragile etc. As an additional tool coverage is helpful. Also 100% coverage may be hard/expensive to achieve.

Comment: As @RomanKonoval stated the coverage is just an indirect measurement. You can for example take away all the assert clauses from your tests and coverage still stays the same. Coverage basically means that your test code has executed the parts of the code that the coverage is indicating. It means you probably have tests but it is not telling anything about the quality of the tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve team culture, put up stuff that acts at the team level.

There's a reason why test suites are usually executed as part of continuous integration builds. Source control hooks are only visible to the developer that commits, while builds are everyone's concern. Any team member can pick up a broken build and fix it, maximizing chances of solving the problem.

> - Run new and changed tests from the NEW commit on the OLD code. Assert
>     that all these tests should be red. If any tests are green, this means
>     that these tests are invalid or redundant, because tested
>     functionality does not exist yet.

Or maybe it does. How do you tell the difference between a refactored test and a test whose Assert changed? Between a new requirement and a requirement that implicitly existed before but we only thought about testing later?

> - Assert that
>     at least all new and changed lines in the NEW code were covered by
>     tests.

100% test coverage is a chimera. An end goal that should be pursued but not stop the line and bite you if not attained.

You are correct in your intentions but I don't believe delegating to an automaton what should be a mindset is a good idea, let alone through technically clunky and maintenance-heavy means.